# In Google Sheets, How Do I Produce a Column of Non-Dupe Values Between Two Columns

Tags: google-sheets, filtering, multiple-columns, drop-duplicates

In this situation, Column A and Column B have a lot of similar values, but are non-identical and not in the same order. Without manipulating the two source columns, how can I create a Column C which only includes non-duplicate values? Given Col A Values, Remove Col B Values, Produces Col C Values

```
If ColA is Ed, Ned, Kyle, Myles, Ruby, Crystal, Eric, Jimi
And ColB is Kyle, Ruby, Crystal, Eric, Ed
Then ColC Would Return is Ned, Myles, Jimi
```

I've tried FILTER() and QUERY() combinations, but to no avail. I've tried ARRAYFORMULA({}) to create a stack, but that hasn't worked either.

Ideally, this would be done without needing to use the ISERROR(SEARCH()) and other multi-step formulae.

Thanks

`=FILTER( ARRAYFORMULA({FILTER($D$11:$D,$D$11:$D<>"");FILTER(Import!$B$3:$B,Import!$B$3:$B<>"")}), ARRAYFORMULA({FILTER($D$11:$D,$D$11:$D<>"");FILTER(Import!$B$3:$B,Import!$B$3:$B<>"")})<>Import!$B$3:$B)`

I expected a stack of my two columns in question using the ARRAYFORMULA({}), and then to be able to filter out the values which appeared in my second column, but array filtering doesn't quite work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `QUERY()` function.

```
=QUERY(A1:A,"select A where not A matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|",1,TOCOL(B1:B,1)) & "'")
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! I also wrapped UNIQUE() around the outside to prevent internally occurring duplicates. Thanks, Harun!

Answer (score 1):

```
=unique(tocol(A:B,1),,1)
```

Stack all the names in a single column (minus blank cells using the *ignore* argument of `tocol`) then use the *exactly_once* argument of `unique` to get those names which are present only once in the combined list.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=FILTER(A1:A, ISNA(MATCH(A1:A, B1:B, 0)))
```

Output:

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: If this answers your question, feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.